# How to prevent DEBUG preprocessor constant from being #DEFINE'd automatically when publishing from msbuild.exe

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, c-preprocessor

We have a C# web application that is being published using a Powershell script. In our C# code we have several places where we check `#if DEBUG` to conditionally compile the application with added support for logging.

The problem is the `DEBUG` constant is defined when we publish from the command line using this command:

```
cmd /c "path\to\msbuild.exe path\to\project.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=Development /verbosity:minimal"
```

We created the "Development" build configuration to correspond to our shared development environment, and then in Visual Studio through the GUI set the "Development" build configuration when creating the publish profile.

**How do I prevent the `DEBUG` preprocessor constant from being automagically defined?**

I must be missing something simple.

Comment: Be specific about what configuration you want to build.  Right now you'll build all of them, some with the wrong DeployOnBuild property which can explain why DEBUG Is defined.  Ought to resemble /p:Configuration=Development.  Should have been easy to see from the msbuild output btw, make sure that you have to fly blind.  Using "cmd.exe /c" has a knack for closing the console window too quickly, /k keeps it around.

Comment: @HansPassant: So specifying `PublishProfile=Development` doesn't choose the build configuration that we choose for that publish profile in Visual Studio? -It's doing the Web.config transforms properly.- Oh! It's transforming Web.config using Web.Debug.config!

Comment: @HansPassant: Specifying the build configuration worked. If you post that as an answer I'll give it a +1 and mark it as the answer. :) Thanks!

Comment: I don't know enough about PublishProfile.  But am 82.45% sure that it was meant to *avoid* having to add a configuration.  So maybe you shouldn't have done this at all, hard to guess.  Post your own answer please.

Comment: @HansPassant: I made that assumption as well, but apparently I was wrong. I still had to specify the build configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the Configuration Property set to Development

**/p:Configuration=Development**

```
cmd /c "path\to\msbuild.exe path\to\project.csproj /p:Configuration=Development/p:DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=Development /verbosity:minimal"
```

By default Visual Studio will create the projects with two configurations:

Debug: This one should be used for development, it includes the DEBUG constant by default.
Release: This one should be used for production

You can also create custom configurations from scratch or based on Debug/Release, if you based a custom configuration "Development" in Debug, it will include the DEBUG constant, you can remove it manually from the .csproj file or right click the project and review the project properties.

Do not confuse the "Configuration" property with a PublishProfile, the PublishProfile is intended to create a Deployment package after compilation, you can use a PublishProfile combining it with Debug or Release.

If you are using web.config transformations be sure to update the "Release" or the custom configuration transform based on your needs.

Comment: While it's true that two build configurations are created by default, we created *another* build configuration: Development. Your answer is correct, except the build configuration should be "Development" in my case. Plus, you can uncheck "Define DEBUG" in the properties for a project and it won't define that constant.

Comment: @GregBurghardt all you said is correct, and I mentioned all that in the my answer in a generic way when I say "custom configuration" or when I mentioned "right click the project and review the project properties". **The answer to your specific question is in the first line and the example in the second one**, the rest is some supporting information. So Is the answer correct for your question or not?

Comment: I edited your answer to be specific to my question, which really only involved changing the `/p:Configuration` param to "Development" since this directly applied to my problem. +1 and marked as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The code that tells msbuild to "automagically" define the DEBUG constant can be found in the .csproj file in the DefineConstants element of the build configuration (see the following excerpt from one of my .csproj files):

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86' ">
  <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
  <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
  <DebugType>full</DebugType>
  <Optimize>false</Optimize>
  <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
  <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
  <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
  <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
</PropertyGroup>
```

You'll need to use a build configuration that does not contain it.